# Show html after completing work with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

codes below is that I made to explain. So it is not complete one. I wrote just enough to explain my question.

html load -> call ajax -> json(response) -> append table row with the json by jquery

whenever I use ajax and update page with response data and append some elements in page with jquery, it shows process of appending one by one in jquery very quickly in screen.

1.Can I have way to show all table at once when it is done appending all elements in for loop with jquery?

2.In my example code, It calls ajax after document get ready with `$(document).ready()` at very first time. It seems quite slow way to show data in table because it call ajax after all html page loaded and then update some part of html with ajax response. Is it wrong way to use ajax???

```
<html>

<body>
   I have to html syntax to show data list.
   <table id="example">
       <thread>
           <th>order</th>
           <th>title</th>
       </thread>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   <button onclick="javascript:loadajaxfunction(parameter to update)">Update</button>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadajaxfunction();
    });

    loadajaxfunction = function(parameter to update) {
    $.ajax({
        url:
        type:
        data:
        success: function(json){
            $tbody = $("#example").find('tbody')
            $row = $('<tr>');

            $.each(json.objects, function(key, value){
                $col = $('td>');
                $col.text(value);
                $row.append($col);
            }
            $tbody.append($row);
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: The reason is because that is what you are doing, adding rows 1 by 1 in your  `.each()` loop on `$tbody` .    Try building the html for the table as a string first, and then set the html of  `#example` to the new table data using `.html( $myVarContainingCustomStringHoldingHtmlForNewTableData )`

Comment: Have a hard time believing you can see each individual element being added. You only ever make one append. As for showing whole table , you could hide it with css and show the table inside callback

Comment: I see. Thank you. I wrote code like, for example, `$col = $('<td'>); $href = $('<a>'); $href.addClass("custom class");  $href.attr("hre", "url"); $href.text("value i want to put"); $col.append($href); $row.append($addcol);`. Because I thought it is easier to edit than this way like adding all in one string: `var example = "<tr><td><a href="url class="custom class">value i want to put</a></td> <tr>"` I thought it is nasty to edit and manage later. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can hide the table at first, and then show it all when we have the response. Like this:

   ```
   <table id="example" style="visibility: hidden"> <!-- Change here -->
      <thread>
          <th>order</th>
          <th>title</th>
      </thread>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

   In JS:

   ```
   loadajaxfunction = function(parameter to update) {
   $.ajax({
       url:
       type:
       data:
       success: function(json){
           $tbody = $("#example").find('tbody')
           $row = $('<tr>');

           $.each(json.objects, function(key, value){
               $col = $('td>');
               $col.text(value);
               $row.append($col);
           }
           $tbody.append($row);
           $("#example").css('visibility', 'visible'); // <--- And here
       }
   });
   ```
2. There is nothing wrong with the way you are using Ajax. If you want to render the table faster, try to return it directly in the HTML from server.
3. If you have to do it at client side, try to build the whole table's HTML first before replace it into the `<table>`, don't access to the DOM too much by appending row by row.

   ```
   loadajaxfunction = function(parameter to update) {
   $.ajax({
       url:
       type:
       data:
       success: function(json){
           $tbody = $("#example").find('tbody')
           $row = $('<tr>');
           // Build html for cols
           var cols = '';
           $.each(json.objects, function(key, value){
               cols += '<td>' + value + '</td>'
           }
           // Append it in all by once
           $row.html(cols);
           $tbody.append($row);
           $("#example").css('visibility', 'visible');
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Showing table looks better with setting visibility attribute! Thank you. So are you saying that it is better to use `append()` as less as possible? It is because of performance issue? Can you explain reason why I should use append() less(or not too much) little bit more detail?

Comment: Manipulating DOMs (`append`) are way more expensive than concatenating strings. So yes, it is a performance issue. Just found this article on Google that may informative for you: http://moduscreate.com/efficient-dom-and-css/

Comment: I read the link you put. Thank you for sharing informative link. It was helpful for me. I need to modify my code to have better performance with using append() less!

Comment: In you very last code, maybe it is 'cols' in each function? And how can you separate each rows with your code? It seems you put all columns together with one string.

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be `cols` in each function, my mistake. I don't really get want you mean by "separate each rows", the code I provided is the same behavior as your which only contains 1 row. If you need to loop over multiple rows, the idea is still the same, you build the html string first, then append it all to `tbody` at once.

Comment: got it. Thank you!