# How to prevent HTML from loading until all server data is processed?

Tags: javascript, html, wait

In my project, my JS receives information from server and then displays it on HTML. However, when I acess the page, the data is not fully loaded yet, so the entire HTML is loaded but the data is not. It forces me to wait X milliseconds to see the last thing to complete the page (the data).

I want to make all elements (divs, span, buttons, my data) load exactly when data's retrieved and ready to be shown. Also, I wanted to do this by displaying a simple waiting gif in order to make the user pacient about it, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  var questionPlace = document.querySelector("#question-place");
  displayPrevious(data, questionPlace);
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src='./scripts/index.js' type='module'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flexbox-container" id="question-place"> <!-- data here --> </div>
    <!-- buttons, divs, etc -->    
</body>
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the data?

Comment: jQuery get request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `window.onload`, use `$.when($.ajax()).then()`:

**Option 1:**
Create every element using `document.createElement`:

```
//window.onload = () => {
$.when($.ajax("file.txt")).then((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
  var elements = [];
  elements.push(document.createElement('div'));
});
```

And the only element that should be in the `<body>` would be your gif:

```
<body>
  <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading...">
</body>
```

**Option 2:**
Set every element to have `display: none;`:

```
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      display: none; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- other elements -->
  <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." onload="(event) => event.target.style.display = 'block'">
</body>
```

And again wait for the call to finish and set everything to block:

```
$.when($.ajax("file.txt")).then((data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
  $("*").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide whatever "parent" HTML element you want and unhide it on the success event for the jQuery get request.

See: [Show html after completing work with ajax and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338038/show-html-after-completing-work-with-ajax-and-jquery)